# c programming error is expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before string constant

Tags: c, compiler-errors

i use gcc to compile my programming,but see error in

```
void sendemail(char *stmpServer, char *serveruser, char *serverpassword);
```

> In file included from test.c:11: sendmail.c:46: error: expected ‘;’,
>   ‘,’ or ‘)’ before string constant sendmail.c:120: error: expected ‘;’,
>   ‘,’ or ‘)’ before string constant

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define stmpServer "smtp.exmail.qq.com"
#define login_name "secbot@test.com"
#define login_passwd "123456"
#define mail_to "root@test.com"
#define ip "127.0.0.1"



int base64_encode(unsigned char *buf, int nLen, char *pOutBuf, int nBufSize);

void sendemail(char *stmpServer, char *serveruser, char *serverpassword);
```

but i modify this

```
        const char * stmpServer = "smtp.exmail.qq.com";
        const char * login_name = "secbot@test.com";
        const char * login_passwd = "123456";
        const char * mail_to = "root@test.com";
        const char * ip = "127.0.0.1";
    ......
    void sendemail(char *stmpServer, char *serveruser, char *serverpassword);

void sendemail(char *stmpServer, char *serveruser, char *serverpassword)
{
    int sockfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr = {0};
    char buf[1500] = {0};
    char rbuf[1500] = {0};
    char login[128] = {0};
    char pass[128] = {0};
    struct hostent *host = NULL;

    if((host = gethostbyname(smtpServer))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Gethostname error, %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
```

in the

> if((host = gethostbyname(smtpServer))==NULL)

say

> sendmail.c:130: error: ‘smtpServer’ undeclared (first use in this
>   function)

Comment: Which lines do the line numbers in the errors refer to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been modified from the original so answers no longer make sense. S.O. is not your own personal syntax checker. Use your compiler for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code:
You declaring s**tmp**Server and using s**mtp**Server for gethostbyname().

Answer (score 2):

Your code is evaluating to

```
void sendemail(char *"smtp.exmail.qq.com", char *serveruser, char *serverpassword);
```

which is not legal C code. Your solution is to change argument name

```
void sendemail(char *someOtherName, char *serveruser, char *serverpassword);
```

or change define name i.e.

```
#define STMP_SERVER "smtp.exmail.qq.com"
```

Comment: but i use like `const char * stmpServer = "smtp.exmail.qq.com";
const char * login_name = "secbot@test.com";
const char * login_passwd = "123456";
const char * mail_to = "root@test.com";
const char * ip = "127.0.0.1"; ........if((host = gethostbyname(smtpServer))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Gethostname error, %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }`  sendmail.c:130: error: ‘smtpServer’ undeclared (first use in this function) @kamil09875

Answer (score 1):

`stmpServer` is a `#define` and used in your signature. In the signature it gets expanded out to the string `"smtp.exmail.qq.com"`